# how to create new dataframe by combining some columns together of existing one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dataframe df like shown:

```
1-1    1-2    1-3    2-1    2-2    3-1    3-2    4-1    5-1
10      3      9      1     3       9      33     10     11
21      31     3      22    21      13     11     7      13
33      22     61     31    35      34     8      10     16
6       9      32     5      4      8      9      6      8
```

where the explanation of the columns as the following:

the first digit is a group number and the second is part of it or subgroup in our example we have groups 1,2,3,4,5 and group 1 consists of 1-1,1-2,1-3.

I would like to create a new dataframe that have only the groups 1,2,3,4,5 without subgroups and choose for each row the max number in the subgroup and be flexible for any new modifications or increasing the groups or subgroups.

The new dataframe I need is like the shown:

```
1    2    3    4    5
10   3    33   10   11
31   22   13   7    13
61   35   34   10   16
32   5    9    6    8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate by columns with `axis=1` and lambda function for split and select first values with `max` and [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

This working correct if numbers of groups contains 2 or more digits.

```
df1 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('-')[0], axis=1).max()
```

Alternative is pass splitted columns names:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('-').str[0], axis=1).max()

print (df1)
    1   2   3   4   5
0  10   3  33  10  11
1  31  22  13   7  13
2  61  35  34  10  16
3  32   5   9   6   8
```

Comment: `split` is redundant unless OP has numbers with more than 1 digit. Nice answer.

Comment: @Ch3steR - yes, in sample data, but for general solution I prefer it.

Comment: @Ch3steR - yop, agree, hard to know if OP think numbers should start with `10-`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.str[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.str.html) or [`.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) here.

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).max())

    1   2   3   4   5
0  10   3  33  10  11
1  31  22  13   7  13
2  61  35  34  10  16
3  32   5   9   6   8
```